# Qt5 How to make class member widget can't be delete

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm building a QTabWidget like browser tabs,it's contain a QToolButton to adding a tab.

Demo image here

[image]

I'm set this button as private member`QToolButton *addTabButton` and initialize on public method `QToolButton* addTabBtn()`.

**What i want**

My idea is let api user to choose using newTab button (   call `tabWidget.addTabBtn()`), and also custom their own button.**But i don't want api user to delete it after call**`tabWidget.addTabBtn()`

```
class BrowserTab : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BrowserTab(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~BrowserTab();
    QToolButton* addTabBtn();

signals:
    void addTabClicked(); //see addTabBtn() fun

private:
    /*Child Widgets*/
    QToolButton *addTabButton;
};

BrowserTab::BrowserTab(QWidget *parent):
    QTabWidget (parent)
{
    addTabButton = nullptr;
   //initialize other things...
}

QToolButton* BrowserTab::addTabBtn()
{
    /*Initial "addTabButton" and return pointer*/
    if(addTabButton == nullptr)
    {
        addTabButton = new QToolButton(this);
        addTabButton->setText("+");
        addTabButton->setShortcut(QKeySequence::AddTab);
        addTabButton->setAutoRaise(true);
        connect(addTabButton,&QToolButton::clicked,this,&BrowserTab::addTabClicked);
        setCornerWidget(addTabButton,Qt::TopRightCorner);
    }
    return addTabButton;
}
```

---

**The Problem**

I found there's problem when i doing this:

```
tabwidget = new BrowserTab(this);
tabwidget->addTab(new QLabel("some content",tabwidget),
                  QString("Loooooooooooooooooong Title"));
tabwidget->addTabBtn();
/* connect signal/slot to button... */

/*Error usage*/
QToolButton *button = tabwidget->addTabBtn();
delete button;
```

It's cause segmentation fault.Is there any technique to prevent user delete button after initialize button?
Maybe return reference of button?

---

**PS:**
My English is pretty limited,sorry for any inconvenience.

---

**Other information:**

Operating System: Win7 32bit
QT Kit: DeskTop Qt5.11.1 MinGw 32bit
Repo:https://github.com/Loukei/Demo-Test

Comment: @eyllanesc The reference doesn't change anything - it can be converted to pointer again.  It's at best a hint to not do so. Another hint should be mentioned in doc. If somebody really wants to delete something he shouldn't then it's difficult to prevent - accept not to return the pointer at all. Total safety against abuse is hard to achieve in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want api user to delete it after call

That's easy: hide the destructor by making it private, and have the class befriend whatever code needs to delete it. Yes, you'll have to derive from the class, and slicing becomes a problem. Generally speaking, you can nudge your users not to do something: C++ is not designed to install safety barriers between the API provider and API consumer: the API consumer can really do whatever they want, as long as they know what they are doing.

In Qt, generally, unless an API specifically mentions that the `QObject` pointer passes ownership, any object pointers you get aren't normally yours to delete.

Comment: That's great! thanks for help!
I lack software design experience.